# ARIMA same model in python (pmdarima) and SPSS but different fitted value

Tags: python, spss

i want to compare between python pmdarima and SPSS ARIMA model, after inserting the same model which is ARIMA(0,0,1) (0,0,0,12) they give me different fitted value, the values are quite close but not exact same i wonder why is this happend ?

this is my python code

```
df=pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
df['Month']= pd.to_datetime(df['Month'])
df.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
df.set_index(df['NPL'].asfreq('1M').index,inplace=True)

import pmdarima.arima
model = pmdarima.arima.ARIMA(order=(0, 0, 1), seasonal_order=(0,0,0,12))
model.fit(df['NPL'])
model.summary()
modelfitting=pd.DataFrame(model.predict_in_sample(),index=df['NPL'].index)
modelfitting
```

[SPSS Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mgrQ.png)
[Python pmdarima Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPNau.png)

Comment: My guess would betl that they both use some kind of iterative algorithm to find the optimal parameters i.e Newton's method, which leads to small difference

Comment: I am using percentage type data so it doesn't look too different, but if the data in million dollars for example, isn't it will going to look so different?, and which one should i use in the future ?

Comment: True, if data is million of dollars it's a big difference. You can either figure out how the parameters are fitted (I'm almost certain its an iterative algorithm) and try to increase the number of steps for both of them to, say 1000000. Then you should see almost identical numbers

Comment: I see that make sense, all right thank you for helping my first ever question in here :D @CutePoison